# Is there an auto-parallelizing compiler for Python?

Tags: python, compiler

I am searching for a compiler that can [automatically parallelize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_parallelization) Python programs. There is a "semi-automatic" parallelization tool called [Pydron](http://www.pydron.org/), but what I need is a fully-automatic parallelizing compiler, similar to [Futhark](https://futhark-lang.org/).

I know that it's possible in theory to translate a small subset of Python into Futhark, but I have not yet found a compiler that can do this. [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/parallel.html) can also parallelize some functions, though it only works with a very limited subset of Python. Is there any compiler (other than Pydron or Numba) that can parallelize Python programs automatically?